# Excel macro to insert rownumber of the row I'm currently working on?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have this code:

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Dim RetVal
 Fil = Range("B1")
 RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\acrord32.exe" & " " & Fil, 1)
 End Sub
```

If I have a file located in a folder, lets say c:\temp\mappe.pdf, and this path is inserted in "B1" in my excel file. The above standing code would open that pdf document.

Now my problem is O have 78987 rows where O need to open the location from the B column in the specific row I'm standing in.

Comment: Could you please be a little more precise about what you're trying to achieve? Do you have many filenames in the B column, and on click on the button you want to open the selected filename?

Comment: Yes i have a alot of filenames, and indeed i want to open the selected filename - That is correct. Sorry if its not explained correctly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ActiveCell` which is a built-in `Range` object of the current selection.  Your code rewrites as

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Dim RetVal
 RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\acrord32.exe" & " " & ActiveCell, 1)
 End Sub
```

Comment: question:
How does the program know i need to grab the string from colum B(it only says ActiveCell now)?

Comment: You can use the `offset` method of `Range` object to get the `Range` object of the cell at column B: Simply change the `ActiveCell` at my revised code as `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2 - ActiveCell.Column)`.  Here, 2 means 2nd column i.e. column B; `2 - ActiveCell.Column` computes the offset value.